# How to query cumulative sum period by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have an issue with table source like this:

[image]

Available month in table is only as is from column month, no April, May, June etc.

I need to create a view to create "Year to Date" table as shown here:

[image]

I need to view all months from Year 2020 January - December with value  based on table source.

VALUE COLUMN filled by Source with same month, but because April not available from source, so it automatically gets set to 0 and others are same

For CUMULATIVE VALUE COLUMN filled by value Sum from last month value

I've tried using case when query but it not simple if I have to many Name and not dynamic

Comment: Look into getting a calendar table; they are an invaluable resource. Then the matter of getting one row per month is more as less as simple as a `JOIN`. As for a cumulative `SUM`, those have been supported since SQL Server 2012. You'll find out how to achieve those with a quick search.

Comment: @Larnu when i join the table with calender table using Year And Month, the view only shown the exists month

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next SQL construction:

```
 WITH Calendar AS (
    -- generate Year, Month table for each Name
    SELECT Year, Month, Name
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS Months(Month)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (2020)) AS years(Year)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Source) AS Names
) SELECT 
    Calendar.Year,
    Calendar.Month,
    Calendar.Name, 
    COALESCE(Source.Value, 0) AS Value,
    SUM(COALESCE(Source.Value, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY Calendar.Name ORDER BY Calendar.Year, Calendar.Month) AS cumulativeSum
FROM Calendar
LEFT JOIN Source ON 
    Source.Year = Calendar.Year AND 
    Source.Month = Calendar.Month AND
    Source.Name = Calendar.Name ;
```

[MSSQL cumulative sum](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=021fdf00184f39f4a30cc1ff49de2374&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

The query use CTE expression for generate calendar table and window function SUM over partition by name to calculate cumulative values

Comment: What if i have many Year e.g 2010-2020  from Column Year, Should i declare it? or using a table?

Comment: I got it how to create dynamic Years , i need to declare colum to distinct table source

Comment: Nice Query @Slava and i need to modif with Real Data table. Thank you